# how to map latitude and longitude to a 3D Sphere

Tags: 3d, three.js, coordinates

Trying to map coordinates with latitude and longitude onto a 3d sphere.

I've tried three different sets of equations from the internet and none of them work. Does anyone know how to do it.

These are the ones I tried that didn't work.

```
var phi   = (90-lat)*(Math.PI/180),
theta = (lon+180)*(Math.PI/180),
x = -((radius) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.cos(theta)),
z = ((radius) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(theta)),
y = ((radius) * Math.cos(phi));

return new THREE.Vector3(x,y,z);


  var height = 600;
  var phi = (lat)*Math.PI/180;
  var theta = (lon-180)*Math.PI/180;

  var x = -(radius+height) * Math.cos(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
  var y = (radius+height) * Math.sin(phi);
  var z = (radius+height) * Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(theta);

  return new THREE.Vector3(x,y,z);



 var x = Math.cos(lon) * Math.sin(lat),
     y = Math.sin(lon) * Math.sin(lat),
     z = Math.cos(lat);
 return  new THREE.Vector3(x,y,z);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah actually this one definitely works!

```
var phi   = (90-lat)*(Math.PI/180),
theta = (lon+180)*(Math.PI/180),
x = -((radius) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.cos(theta)),
z = ((radius) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(theta)),
y = ((radius) * Math.cos(phi));

return new THREE.Vector3(x,y,z);
```